# DomCrawler, парсинг вложенных элементов

Tags: php, парсер, symfony

`$crawler->filter('div')` имеет значение

```
<p class="с1">
 <b class="с2">Text 1</b>
  Text 2
</p>
```

Как добраться до "Text 2"?

Comment: `$crawler->filter('div p.c1')->innerText()` или `$crawler->filter('div')->children('p.c1')->innerText()`

Comment: а если класс с пробелом class="с1 gkf"?

Comment: Обычные селекторы.. "класс с пробелом" это 2 класса

Comment: как обратиться, если два класса?

Comment: `'div.class1.class2'`

Comment: Спасибо большое